# Create domain name

Tags: linux, ubuntu, localhost, domain-name

How can I create a domain name for local purposes?

for example I have a local web application enviroment in `http://localhost:8000` but I would like to have it in `http://dev` instead.

I am using Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: Used parenthesis between http because, due my low reputation was not posible to post more than one link.

Comment: You just have to format the URLs as code like Lawrence did for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use a text editor of your choosing to edit your `/etc/hosts` file. Add two entries that look like this:

```
127.0.0.1   dev
::1         dev
```

These hosts entries map the "dev" hostname to your machine's loopback interface (address 127.0.0.1 under IPv4, and 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 for IPv6). After saving, "http://dev" should behave identically to "http://localhost".

(NB: You will need superuser permissions to edit the `/etc/hosts` file.)

Comment: aliases are the better way: 127.0.0.1 localhost dev - this way applications that rely on the name(!) localhost will still work and http:/dev will too. The port is another issue..

Comment: I do not believe having multiple entries for 127.0.0.1 affects the use of "localhost".

Comment: i agree, multiple entries for 127.0.0.1 is fine

Answer (score 0):

I'm running [DNSMasq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dnsmasq) for this kind of thing. It has DHCP server too.